# How to create attributes based on the data elements catagory in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to transform the following table into crosstab in sql server. Do I have to use the Pivot method or CASE statement to get the required output?

Input-

[image]

Output-

[image]

So far I have tried the following code-

```
TRANSFORM [PODB].[Model]
SELECT [PODB].[PO], [PODB].[Color]
FROM PODB
GROUP BY [PODB].[PO], [PODB].[Color], [PODB].[Model]
PIVOT [PODB].[Car Make];
```

But it is not giving me the exact output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` expression to do conditional aggergation:

```
select po, color, 
       isnull(max(case when [Car Make] = 'toyota' then model end), 'N/A') as toyota,
       . . .
       isnull(max(case when [Car Make] = 'hyundai' then model end), 'N/A') as hyundai
from podb p
group by po, color;
```